# Echo value to Linux console

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, system-calls

How can I, in C, output a value from a syscall to the Linux console so that it will be visible after a `dmesg`? What method do I use for printing?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're looking for the `printk()` function; some documentation on the types that it supports is found in `Documentation/printk-formats.txt`. It is defined in `kernel/printk.c`.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you mean in the user-space. You can write the string to `/dev/kmsg`. In shell, just `echo` it. In C, it would be also very easy.

```
[root@cr0 ~]# echo hello > /dev/kmsg
[root@cr0 ~]# dmesg | tail -1
[24156.408735] hello
```

But if you mean in kernel space, of course, you need to call `printk()`.

Answer (score 1):

In addition, you might be interested (even if that does not answer exactly your question), by the [openlog & syslog](http://linux.die.net/man/3/syslog) functions. From within an application, they are the proper way to get system logging.